# Cannot play swf file with gnash

Tags: flash, gnash

I downloaded [here](http://landsurvival.com/thinkinginc/Chapters/chap4/) all the `.swf` and `.mp3` files.

When I run

```
$ gnash Lecture.swf
```

it ends with `Aborted (core dumped)`

Can I play somehow the whole lecture or convert it to another format and then play it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWF files are most frequently played from a web browser that supports the Adobe Flash Player plug-in.

With this installed, a web browser like Firefox is capable of opening SWF files automatically.

If you have a local SWF file on your computer, **simply drag and drop it into a browser window** to play it.